# Como posso associar valores digitados e que serão guardados em um vetor, a uma opção de um menu?

Tags: python, algoritmo

Como posso associar um range de valores de 1 a 6 a cada uma das opções do menu de sistemas operacionais que possuo na lista? A minha ideia é que quando eu digite três vezes o número 1 por exemplo, isso conte como três votos para a opção Windows Server, para no fim eu poder imprimir ele como o mais votado da enquete.

Pensei em tentar resolver com um dicionário, porém teria que digitar o nome do sistema operacional como chave toda vez que eu quisesse computar um voto

```
votos = []
valor = 0
mais_votado = []
maisvotado = 0
maiorpercent = 0

print('Qual o melhor sistema operacional para uso em servidores?''\n''As respostas são:''\n'
      '1 - Windows Server''\n'
      '2 - Unix''\n'
      '3 - Linux''\n'
      '4 - Netware''\n'
      '5 - Mac OS''\n'
      '6 - Outro')

valor = int(input('Insira o número correspondente a alguma das opções:'))
while 0 < valor <= 6:
    valor = int(input('Insira o número correspondente a alguma das opções:'))
    votos.append(valor)
    if valor > 6:
        valor = int(input('Valor inválido,insira um valor válido:'))
total = len(votos)
for i in range(total):
    if votos.count(i) > 1:
        mais_votado.append(i)
for i in mais_votado:
    if i > maisvotado:
        maisvotado = i
for i in votos:
    percent = (i * 100)/sum(votos)
    if percent > maiorpercent:
        maiorpercent = percent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Pensei em tentar resolver com um dicionário, porém teria que digitar o nome do sistema operacional como chave toda vez que eu quisesse computar um voto.*

Na verdade não, com um dicionário você pode usar o valor da opção como chave:

```
opcoes = { '1': 'Windows Server', '2': 'Unix', '3': 'Linux', '4': 'Netware', '5': 'Mac OS', '6': 'Outro' }
```

Mantive as chaves como strings, pois aí você não precisa convertê-las para números. Basta verificar se o que foi digitado é uma chave válida.

Então um "rascunho" do código seria assim (também adicionei uma opção para interromper o *loop*):

```
opcoes = { '1': 'Windows Server', '2': 'Unix', '3': 'Linux', '4': 'Netware', '5': 'Mac OS', '6': 'Outro' }
texto_opcoes = '\n'.join(f'{i} - {desc}' for i, desc in opcoes.items())
while True:
    voto = input(f'Qual o melhor sistema operacional para uso em servidores?\nAs respostas são:\n: {texto_opcoes} (0 para sair):')
    if voto == '0':
        break
    elif voto in opcoes: # se é uma opção válida
        # computa o voto
    else:
        print('Opção inválida')
```

Para computar os votos, podemos usar um [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), que além de manter a contagem de cada opção, também ajuda na hora de obter o mais votado, com o uso do [método `most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common). Porém, temos que tratar também os casos de empate, então temos que mostrar todos que têm a mesma quantidade de votos do mais votado:

```
from collections import Counter

votos = Counter()
opcoes = { '1': 'Windows Server', '2': 'Unix', '3': 'Linux', '4': 'Netware', '5': 'Mac OS', '6': 'Outro' }
texto_opcoes = '\n'.join(f'{i} - {desc}' for i, desc in opcoes.items())
while True:
    voto = input(f'Qual o melhor sistema operacional para uso em servidores?\nAs respostas são:\n{texto_opcoes} (0 para sair):')
    if voto == '0':
        break
    elif voto in opcoes: # se é uma opção válida
        votos.update([voto])
    else:
        print('Opção inválida')

mais_votado = votos.most_common(1)[0]
print(f'Mais votados (com {mais_votado[1]} votos cada):')
for opcao, qtd_votos in votos.items():
    if qtd_votos == mais_votado[1]:
        print(f'- {opcoes[opcao]} ')
```

Ou seja, eu computo os votos, sempre atualizando o `Counter`. Depois, vejo o mais votado. Em caso de empate, `most_common` retornará um deles, então eu percorro o `Counter` e imprimo somente os elementos que têm a mesma quantidade de votos do mais votado. Repare que as chaves do `Counter` são as mesmas do dicionário `opcoes`, e eu as mantive como strings porque o fato delas serem números é circunstancial, e desta forma o algoritmo se mantém o mesmo caso você queira mudar as chaves (por exemplo, se fossem opção "a" para "Windows", "b" para "Unix", etc, bastaria mudar as chaves do dicionário, e o restante do código permaneceria igual).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda,consegui resolver usando essa solução com dicionários mesmo,acabou ficando mais prático

Answer (score -1):

Bom fiz um sistema bem simples mas acho que entrega oque você procura:

```
print('Qual o melhor sistema operacional para uso em servidores?''\n''As respostas são:''\n'
      '1 - Windows Server''\n'
      '2 - Unix''\n'
      '3 - Linux''\n'
      '4 - Netware''\n'
      '5 - Mac OS''\n'
      '6 - Outro')

votes = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
while True:
    vote = input('Insira o número correspondente a alguma das opções: ')
    print('')
    if vote == '1':
        votes[0] = votes[0] + 1
    elif vote == '2':
        votes[1] = votes[1] + 1
    elif vote == '3':
        votes[2] = votes[2] + 1
    elif vote == '4':
        votes[3] = votes[3] + 1
    elif vote == '5':
        votes[4] = votes[4] + 1
    elif vote == '6':
        votes[5] = votes[5] + 1

    if max(votes) == votes[0]:
        print('O sistema mais votado é Windows Server com: ', max(votes), ' Votos\n')
    elif max(votes) == votes[1]:
        print('O sistema mais votado é Unix com: ', max(votes), ' Votos\n')
    elif max(votes) == votes[2]:
        print('O sistema mais votado é Linux com: ', max(votes), ' Votos\n')
    elif max(votes) == votes[3]:
        print('O sistema mais votado é Netware com: ', max(votes), ' Votos\n')
    elif max(votes) == votes[4]:
        print('O sistema mais votado é Mac OS com: ', max(votes), ' Votos\n')
    elif max(votes) == votes[5]:
        print('O sistema mais votado é Outro com: ', max(votes), ' Votos\n')
```